# my second activity is not returning result for first one

Tags: android

I am trying to make an app in which `MainActivity` ask for result from `Main2Activity`
code for `MainActivity` is:

```
package hello.option_menu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.ye.collor.stackapplication.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button bt;
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt);
        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv) ;
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i,1);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==1)
        {
            String message=data.getStringExtra("message");
            tv.setText(message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.jai, menu);

        return true;
    }

}
```

code of `Main2Activity` is:

```
package hello.option_menu;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.ye.collor.stackapplication.R;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button bt;
    EditText et;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                String message=et.getText().toString();
                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("message",message);
                setResult(1,intent);
                finish();

            }
        });
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        menu.add("hello");

        MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.jai,menu);

        return true;
    }

}
```

so the  view of my app is:[my MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPMwO.png)

[my Main2Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGkxI.png)

So when I click the send button after typing the text  in `Main2Activity` to set the text  written in `MainActivity` it didn't do that.It still remain "hello world",so text do not change .I am unable to trouble shoot this problem.

Comment: Hi Jai jazz,you can check my answer.

Comment: Check my answer, Problem is not because of result code.

Answer (score 1):

In your `MainActivity2` Change

```
setResult(1,intent);
```

to

```
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
```

What you are trying to do is set the hardcoded value of `RESULT_TYPE` as 1 which is the int value for `RESULT_FIRST_USER` whereas what you intended to do was set `RESULT_OK`

Also the Value of 1 that you are assuming would be requestcode in m=MainActivity2 is actually not `REQUEST_CODE` but `RESULT_CODE`. The requestCode remains in MainActivity and can be used to distinguish between different activities that you open.

Also you can change your `onActivityResult` as follows to keep it more safer

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==1 && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
        String message=data.getStringExtra("message");
        tv.setText(message);
    }
}
```

**Update 1**
Also as you mentioned it crashes after this, its because your TextView is not initialized properly in MainActivity.

So in MainActivity Change

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv) ;
```

to

```
tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv) ;
```

so that your Textview that you declared Globally is assigned the value when you return in `OnActivityResult`

Comment: not working sir,now on clicking send button app stops

Comment: If its stopping what is the error log say. it cannot be because of this code but something else

Comment: still not working,after pressing send button text do not change

Comment: Its because in your MainActivity you have done 'TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv) ;' instead of 'tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);' This creates another local variable and doesn't assign the text to your Global variable. hence the crash as well

Comment: @Jaijazz Try the code now as I mentioned above and let me know

Comment: I think we can send **RESULT_FIRST_USER** as a result code that is not at all a problem as per android doc

Comment: We can send but that means you have to Have your own custom Results defined and that you would be handling the result events accordingly. From the looks of the requirement of the OP, it doesn't seem anywhere necessary to opt out of standard Result types and choose a custom one.

Comment: Please [refer this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) in **Starting Activities and Getting Results** title

Comment: No sir still the same problem

Comment: Can you add your updated code here and also if you see any error in the logs

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran I am not trying to argue. I am just saying the OP has not understood the difference between requestCode and resultCode. It is by chance that his requestCode is 1 which matches with the RESULT_FIRST_USER. tomorrow if he uses 101, it will not work. So trying to explain the right way to do it. I am 100% OP did not intent to use RESULT_FIRST_USER as resultCode

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the `Main2Activity`.

```
  String message = et.getText().toString();
  Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("message", message);
  setResult(1, intent);
  finish();
```

Just change to this `Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);`

Add in `MainActivity`

**change**

```
Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt);
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv)
```

**to**

```
bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt);
tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv)
```

And change in `onActivityResult()` method

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1 || resultCode == 1) {
        String message = data.getStringExtra("message");
        tv.setText(message);
        Log.e("resultCode", resultCode + "");
        Log.e("message", message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this will help you.

Comment: Could you have `Log.e("message", message);` in it.Is messge `null`?

Comment: I use your code to work.And it worked.So you can have a try.